# flash/modules/global/app/ffmpeg.exe is Non-Executable

Tags: ffmpeg, boonex-dolphin

I cannot install dolphin. Always it returns back the same error:
`The following files have inappropriate permissions:
   flash/modules/global/app/ffmpeg.exe;`
And if I scroll down, I can se this:
`flash/modules/global/app/ffmpeg.exe -- Non-Executable`
And I made it executable, chmod777 and I didn't work, so I tried with chmod755 and all chmods with executable parametres. And it didn't work anyway.
Help please! I need to get this working asap, is for a business!
Thanks people.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with Chmod. Did you try it using command-line tool instead of graphic applications? (which might have bugs or limitations sometimes)

As an alternative option, I recommend to download ffmpeg.exe from the official boonex website, on the bottom of the page, here : http://www.boonex.com/paymentprovider/payment

Either you are on Windows or Linux, just replace your original ffmpeg.exe by this one which has good rights included, it should solve your problem.